# How to understand "MoveOnCopy(T&&) -> MoveOnCopy<T>" definition?

Tags: c++

I come across following `C++` [code](https://github.com/cpp-taskflow/cpp-taskflow/blob/9cf75aeec0fefa98e597b53169a615acec9e921e/taskflow.hpp#L97):

```
// Struct: MoveOnCopy
template <typename T>
struct MoveOnCopy {

  MoveOnCopy(T&& rhs) : object(std::move(rhs)) {}
  MoveOnCopy(const MoveOnCopy& other) : object(std::move(other.object)) {}

  T& get() { return object; }

  mutable T object; 
};

template <typename T>
MoveOnCopy(T&&) -> MoveOnCopy<T>;
```

I am a little confused about following statement:

```
template <typename T>
MoveOnCopy(T&&) -> MoveOnCopy<T>;
```

And just guess its a function definition which returns a `MoveOnCopy` struct. I checked [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) and [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), but can't find similar example. Could anyone help to elaborate this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a C++17 deduction guide. It tells the compiler how to deduce the template argument for `MoveOnCopy` from constructor arguments. For example, in:

```
MoveOnCopy m(123);
```

an object of type `MoveOnCopy<int>` will be constructed.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) for more details.